# Running usb_cam across VNC and getting Cannot identify '/dev/video0'

Tags: docker, ros-kinetic, usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys, I was running a docker container that contains the normal ros packages and usb_cam. I visualized the ubuntu interface through a VNC (localhost:5900) and tried `roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch` in the VNC viewer. However, I got:

```
[ERROR] [1559585420.922861365]: Cannot identify '/dev/video0': 2, No such file or directory
```

When I tried `ls -ltrh /dev/video*`, I got `ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory`.
Everything works when I tried the aboves on my local computer, are there any additional steps I need to make so I can use my webcam in a docker image?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324574/running-usb_cam-across-vnc-and-getting-cannot-identify-%27/dev/video0%27/) by [Kolohe113](https://answers.ros.org/users/36311/kolohe113/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Everything works when I tried the aboves on my local computer, are there any additional steps I need to make so I can use my webcam in a docker image?

yes: mount the device file into your Docker container (using `-v` or `--volume`), similar to how you would do that with other files and directories.

This is not really a ROS issue btw: I would suggest you try to search for how to make Linux device files available to/in Docker containers.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kolohe113](https://answers.ros.org/users/36311/kolohe113/) on 2019-06-03**:
Solved by following instruction described here:
https://medium.com/@zwinny/docker-using-webcam-9fafb26cf1e6